# Why does calling AsEnumerable() on a DataTable prevent a GridView from binding to it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, ado.net, ienumerable

In my .aspx page, I have an `<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="CustomerGridView">` control which I bind like this:

```
public partial class InsertCustomer : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ViewCustomer();
        }
    }

    private void ViewCustomer()
    {
        var manager = new DomainManager();
        var result = manager.FindAll(new Customer());
        this.CustomerGridView.DataSource = result;
        this.CustomerGridView.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Here is the `DomainManager` class:

```
public class DomainManager
{
    readonly StringBuilder _queryBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    private Type _entityType;
    readonly SQLHelper _sqlHelper = new SQLHelper();

    public IEnumerable FindAll<T>(T entity)
    {
        _entityType = entity.GetType();
        var query = string.Format("select * from {0}", _entityType.Name);
        var dt = _sqlHelper.FillDataTable(query);
        return dt.AsEnumerable();
    }
}
```

The problem is that my grid is not being bound correctly. Why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing

```
return dt.AsEnumerable();
```

to

```
return dt.DefaultView;
```

**Explanation:** By default, a `GridView` binds to actual properties of an object. For example, if the data source is a `List<Customer>`, then you can bind to the `Name` property of each `Customer`. But when the data source is a `DataTable` of customers, then each customer is represented by a `DataRow`, and a `DataRow` does *not* have a `Name` property that the `GridView` can bind to.

To support dynamic properties, an object must implement the `ICustomTypeDescriptor` interface. This interface is implemented by `DataRowView` but not `DataRow`. By changing the code to return `dt.DefaultView` (which is a `DataView`), you provide the `GridView` with a collection of `DataRowView` objects that it can bind to.

Now you might be wondering why

```
this.CustomerGridView.DataSource = dt;
```

works, but

```
this.CustomerGridView.DataSource = dt.AsEnumerable();
```

doesn't.

The reason is that `DataTable` implements the `IListSource` interface, which tells the `GridView` "don't use me as the data source, use my `DefaultView` instead." But `AsEnumerable()` returns a wrapper object that doesn't implement `IListSource`, so the `GridView` doesn't know how to get to the `DefaultView`.

Comment: using dt.DefaultView gives me this error `enumerable does not implement IEnumerable<>` Any ideas ?

Comment: What are you passing DefaultView to? DataView implements the **non-generic** IEnumerable interface but not `IEnumerable<T>`, so you cannot directly pass DefaultView to something that expects `IEnumerable<T>`.